# What would the toQueryParams() will return when the url http://www.google.com in prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, query-string

I have a scenario to get Query Params from the URL. There is a method called `toQueryParams()` which will get all params.
But when the URL is `http://www.google.com` the same method returning the same URL as query param, URL as key and undefined as value.

```
var param = window.location.href.toQueryParams()
```

This is the code I have used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the URL has no query parameters ie no `?` or `&` part of the URL then there are no query parameters except for the URL.

So how I usually use this method on a given URL http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?arg=2500&search=Smith

```
var param = window.location.href.toQueryParams();
if(param.arg != undefined)
{
    //do things with the arg parameter
}
if(param.search != undefined)
{
    //do things with the search param
    alert('User has selected '+param.search+' as the search parameter');
}
```

So if the given param does not exist then I don't try and handle it. The method `toQueryParam()` is giving you a error you can handle instead of an Exception or full on JS error that stops your JS execution.

Comment: When the url is formed dynamically how can we check,whether the param is undefined or not.

Comment: regardless if the url is created dynamically checking if `param.search` is undefined will still work - and that will tell you if you have to handle it

Answer (score 0):

I tried in the following way,  to resolve this issue.

```
if (window.location.search != "") { // this means the url has no query params
var param = window.location.href.toQueryParams(); // param Object will holds queryparams in key and value form
} else {
var param = new Object(); // param will has no queryParmas but, it is an empty object
}
```